# Casting an instance of a generic class into another whats the use?

Tags: java, generics, types, casting

I know this is possible but whats the use? Since it can only cast the same type as the object being casted?

```
class Example<X>{ 
//statements
}

//then this is declared
Example<Integer> x = new Example<Integer>();

//This is allowed
(Example<Integer>) x;

//this is not allowed, so what's the use?
(Example<Long>) x;
```

Comment: It doesn't compile, so nobody can use that. I don't understand your question.

Comment: You can do `(Example<Long>)(Example) x`. But it's stupid and error prone. Why do you want to cast to `Example<Long>` in the first place?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov Well my book said its possible, but it didn't give a specific use for it.. so i though i was missing a point

Comment: @vincentbelkin can you post here exact quote from book?

Comment: "Yes, you can cast one instance of a generic class into another, but only if the two are otherwise compatible and their type arguments ae the same." (Herbert Schildt,2012)

Comment: @vincentbelkin I think he's describing following: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); (ArrayList<String>) list`. Type arguments must be the same.

Comment: Read "their type arguments are the same". Your example is not what the book says.

Comment: So in generics you can cast "left" parts (actual classes) not "right" parts (type classes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see some use in the first one. Since java decides the type on runtime, in this particular case you could declare x like an instance of object, and by downcasting it in that line, you're telling the compiler that x is, indeed, Example.

I think the second one is not allowed in your example because Long is not an subclass of Integer, is more like a brother, since I think both inherit from Number.

Check the docs: [Long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) || [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)

So, if you had done something like:

```
Example<Number> x = new Example<Number>();

(Example<Integer>) x;
(Example<Long>) x;
```

And then if you dropped your x in something like a visitor, with overloading, your x would've falled inside your `Example<Long>` implementation instead of your `Example<Integer>` implementation.

Guess I got a little bit confusing in there, but hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The quote of the book does not say that you express by example. The book says that you can simply apply the normal rules for casting, as long as the **type arguments are the same**.

Answer (score 0):

> so what's the use?

There are lots of uses.

For example, for casting a wildcard parameter to a specific parameter, or more specific wildcard parameter:

```
Example<?> x;
Example<? extends Number> y;
Example<Integer> z;
y = (Example<? extends Number>)x;
z = (Example<Integer>)x;
z = (Example<Integer>)y;
```

or for casting the actual class to a more specific one:

```
Example<Integer> x;
SubExample<Integer> y;
y = (SubExample<Integer>)x;
```